# Proving whether quotient ring is a field

Tags: ring-theory, proof-explanation

> Consider $R[x]/(x^6 + 5x + 5)$ where $R = \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{C}$ in turn. Determine whether $R[x]/(x^6 + 5x + 5)$ is an integral domain and whether it is a field for each choice of $R$.

The only case I have figured out is when $R = \mathbb{Q}$. I proved a lemma stating that when $F$ is a field $F[x]/(f(x))$ is a field if and only if $f(x)$ is irreducible. I proved by Eisenstein's criteria that $x^5 + 5x + 5$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field, $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^6 + 5x + 5)$ is a field and therefore an integral domain.

I cannot use this same result for $\mathbb{Z}$ because $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field. I can use the result for $\mathbb{C}[x]$, but I need to show that $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^6 + 5x + 5)$ is not an integral domain, finding a zero divisor, but I don't have any intuition for how to do this.

Any help on the $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ cases would be great.

Answer (score 1):

A quotient ring is a field (integral domain) iff the ideal we quotient by is maximal (prime).

For $\Bbb Z$, the ideal is clearly not maximal, as it is strictly contained in, for instance, $(x^6+5x+5, 5)$ (which also isn't maximal, but that's beside the point).

For $\Bbb C$, consider the fundamental theorem of algebra to show that $(x^6+5x+5)$ isn't maximal (or even prime).

Comment: The fundamental theorem of algebra lets me pull out $6$ roots and write $x^6 + 5x + 5$ as $\prod\limits_{I=1}^6 (x - x_i) a(x)$. How can I use that to prove that it isn't a prime ideal, though?

Comment: @StanMS First off, no $a(x)$, just $\prod_{I=1}^6 (x - x_i)$. Or alternatively, no $\prod$, just $(x-x_1)a(x)$. At any rate, you have a product that is contained in the ideal, but none of the factors are (the ideal contains no polynomials of degree 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5). That's exactly what non-prime means.